# How to horizontally center div?

Tags: css, html

```html
<div style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="width:50%; background:#000">
        <p style="color:#fff">Text must be left.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me How can I centrally align sub div and paragraph must be left. Please refer https://vsss.co.in/index.php/User?

Comment: Hey, can you look at https://vsss.co.in/index.php/User?

Comment: you simply added the margin in the wrong div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add `margin:0 auto` to the element you need to center.

```html
<div style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; background:#000">
        <p style="color:#fff">Text must be left.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, can you look at https://vsss.co.in/index.php/User?

Comment: @SuthanBala , are you see `vsss.co.in/index.php/User`? your answer dont help to Bala.questioner use of margin: 0 auto already.

Comment: @RushabhShah sorry just looked at it, where do you want me to see? BTW, when you use `margin:0 auto;` a width must also be present to that element.

Comment: @RushabhShah if you are referring to `.sign-in-page` div, that div has 100% width, so you won't see the effect. If you change the width to something lower, you will see it centering